# changing the background image on mouse down

Tags: css, image, html, background

I have a slight problem that I swear should work...it kinda seems like a silly question ...but here it is ...
i want a div i created to act as a button ...it how ever does not want to change its background when i click on it( giving the effect of a button)
here's my code :

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <style>
 #button1 {
     width:100px;
     height:50px;
     background-image:url(normalbutton.jpg)
 }
 </style>
 </head>

 <body class="asd">
 <div id="container">
 <a href="#">
 <div id="button1" onmousedown="document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundImage='url(onmousedownbutton.jpg)'"></div></a>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: 1) You shouldn't put inline javascript. 2) you can refer to your item using `this` keyword in your function. 3) It may be that the path to your image is not good... check this first

Comment: 4), your HTML is invalid. You are using `"` inside `"`, what will give you probably an error. (`"document.getElementById("button1")..."`)

Comment: thanks ...i thought of trying to avoid creating some script ..anyways ..thanks :)

Comment: As @Bartdude said, inline js is your problem. Check this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/CcKM4/** to see how to put that to work.

Answer (score 2):

I think using jQuery it will be easy :

```
$("#button1").mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(1.jpg)'}) 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You use double quotes inside double quotes. Change the quotes around *button1* to single quotes like this:
`<div id="button1" onmousedown="document.getElementById('button1').style.backgroundImage='url(onmousedownbutton.jpg)'"></div>`

Further notes:

- Your `<div id="container">` isn't closed
- You can't use `<div>` inside of `<a>`

Answer (score 1):

Just use css :

HTML

```
<html> 
<body class="asd">
 <div id="container">
   <a href="#">
     <div id="button1" ></div>
   </a>
  </div>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

CSS

```
#button1 {width:500px;height:500px;background:red}
#button1:hover {background:green;}
#button1:active {background:grey;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change the mouse down like this**

```
 <a href="#">
 <div id="button1" onmousedown="this.style.backgroundImage='url(http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT6-aJ6Hz_oXi_M2ZScbEiNGKZFKN3hyhffh2NMWTmbgU2WX-IZKA)'">Button
</div>
</a>
```

[**LiveDemo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4YRuf/10/)

```
onmousedown="this.style.backgroundImage='url(http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT6-aJ6Hz_oXi_M2ZScbEiNGKZFKN3hyhffh2NMWTmbgU2WX-IZKA)'">
```

I have used some images from Google it will look good with some custom images. :)

Answer (score 0):

You also can try css:

```
#button1:focus {
  background: url(onmousedownbutton.jpg);
}
```

or

```
#button1:active{
  background: url(onmousedownbutton.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Bushan's answer, this will swap to the downclick image when mouse is held down, and revert back to the original image when mouse button is released.

```
$("#button1").mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(image2.jpg)'}) 
}).mousedown(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(image1.jpg)'}) 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="button1" style="background-image:url('image1.jpg');"></div>
```

Sources/References:

[CSS background-image - What is the correct usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851724/css-background-image-what-is-the-correct-usage)